# spring boot spring rabbit: How to create a rabbit template to send a message within a listener

Tags: spring-amqp

I have a simple listener that is receiving messages from Rabbitmq.  I would like to modify the message and publish it to a new exchange/queue.  I have been unable to get a rabbit template to work within a listener.  Any help would be appreciated.  My code is below, when I tried to autowire the template I get

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.example.Consumer.onMessage(Consumer.java:27) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
```

Classes:

```
package com.example;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;


@SpringBootApplication
public class RabbittestApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(RabbittestApplication.class, args);
    }
}


package com.example;

import org.springframework.amqp.core.AcknowledgeMode;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactory;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class RabbitConfig {

    private static final String SIMPLE_MESSAGE_QUEUE = "qDLX1.dlx";

    @Bean
    public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
        CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new CachingConnectionFactory("RabbitErl19");
        connectionFactory.setUsername("gregg");
        connectionFactory.setPassword("gregg");
        connectionFactory.setPort(5672);
        connectionFactory.setVirtualHost("dlxtest");
        return connectionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate() {
        RabbitTemplate template = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory());
        return template;
    }



    @Bean
    public SimpleMessageListenerContainer listenerContainer() {
        SimpleMessageListenerContainer listenerContainer = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer();
        listenerContainer.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
        listenerContainer.setQueueNames(SIMPLE_MESSAGE_QUEUE);
        listenerContainer.setMessageListener(new Consumer());
        listenerContainer.setAcknowledgeMode(AcknowledgeMode.AUTO);
        return listenerContainer;
    }



}

package com.example;


import org.springframework.amqp.core.Message;
import org.springframework.amqp.core.MessageListener;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;


@Component
public class Consumer implements MessageListener {

    @Autowired
    private RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate;

    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message message) {


        System.out.println("Body: "+new String(message.getBody()));


        System.out.println();


        message.getMessageProperties().setExpiration("5000");        
        rabbitTemplate.send("xDLX1.delay", "xq1.retry", message);



    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is your code:

```
listenerContainer.setMessageListener(new Consumer());
```

As you see it is absolutely normal that `@Autowired` doesn't work. Just because you have bypassed dependency injection.

Since your `Consumer` is marked with `@Component` you can simply inject it into that `SimpleMessageListenerContainer` bean definition:

```
@Bean
public SimpleMessageListenerContainer listenerContainer(Consumer consumer)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks that did it, I changed my code to what is below and it worked.  Your help is much appreciated!

```
@Autowired
private Consumer consumer;


@Bean
public SimpleMessageListenerContainer listenerContainer() {
    SimpleMessageListenerContainer listenerContainer = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer();        
    listenerContainer.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
    listenerContainer.setQueueNames(SIMPLE_MESSAGE_QUEUE);
    listenerContainer.setMessageListener(consumer);
    listenerContainer.setAcknowledgeMode(AcknowledgeMode.AUTO);
    return listenerContainer;
}
```